# "get unexpected responses" vs. "get unexpected response" vs. "get an unexpected response"

Tags: singular-vs-plural, indefinite-article, plural-forms

Which of the following three sentences would be correct? What are the differences between them?

1. You don’t have to check the correctness of the database table unless you get unexpected **response** for your test cases.
2. You don’t have to check the correctness of the database table unless you get unexpected **responses** for your test cases.
3. You don’t have to check the correctness of the database table unless you get **an** unexpected **response** for your test cases.

Comment: #2 is correct. #1 would be correct with an article "an unexpected response".

Comment: @user178049 so what is the difference between 
1). ...an unexpected response...
2).....unexpected responses..

Comment: The former is singular, and the latter is plural.

Comment: @user178049  I understand that part. But in terms of meaning, are there any differences?

Comment: In action, is the "unexpected response" a one-shot occurrence before the following action (checking the correctness of the database table) or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You don’t have to check the correctness of the database table unless you get **unexpected response** for your test cases.

Without any context, this is ungrammatical. It *could* be correct if somehow "unexpected response" was defined as something other that what is assumed.

> You don’t have to check the correctness of the database table unless you get **unexpected responses** for your test cases.

Do not check for correctness unless you receive some (usually two or more, but in this context could be interpreted as one or more) unexpected respones.

> You don’t have to check the correctness of the database table unless you get **an unexpected response** for your test cases.

Do not check for correctness unless you receive one (usually interpreted as at least one) unexpected response.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Your answer is clear.  It didn't confuse me.